# How to recreate docker-machine after accidentally deleting its underlying vm

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-machine

I created a docker machine with the following command:

```
docker-machine create --driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Primary Virtual Switch" vmxy
```

Everything works fine, but today I deleted the `vmxy` in the hyper-v manager. I tried to recreate it again with the same command, but `docker-machine` throws an error that the host already exist.

`docker-machine rm vmxy` does not work either. `docker-machine ls` also lists the `vmxy`.

I found a directory called `C:\Users\LocalUser\.docker\machine\machines\vmxy` and renamed it to `vmxyOLD`. After that the create command works and created a new virtual machine `vmxy`.

Now my question is, can I delete the renamed folder `vmxyOLD` without damaging my system, or is this a bad idea?